# Save toggle state + class toggle using cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have around 4 buttons that shows content when clicked

```
$(function() {
  $(".hidden").hide();

  $('.button').on('click', function() {
       var circle = $(this).attr('data-circle');
       $('.'+circle).toggle();
       $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    });
});
```

My html

```
<button class="button" data-circle="biographies">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> biographies
</button>

<button class="button" data-circle="pictures">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> pictures
</button>

<button class="button" data-circle="poetry">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> poetry
</button>

<div class="biographies hidden">content</div>
<div class="pictures hidden">content</div>
<div class="poetry hidden">content</div>
```

The content is hidden because I want to reveal it each time it is clicked, I'm also using font awesome as you can see and this gives me a plus sign when the content is visible and a minus sign once it is hidden.

How can I save the toggle state of both the content and icon class?

http://jsfiddle.net/hv4aywa4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fellow redditor helped with this one and suggested that I use localstorage, here it is if anyone wants the answer

```
var localStorageKey = "app_state";

// to preserve state, you first need to keep track of it
  var default_state = {
  biographies: false,
  pictures: false,
  poetry: false
 }

 var saved_state = localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey);

 // ternary operator which means if `saved_state` evaluates to `true` we parse it and use that value for `state`; otherwise use `default_state`
var state = saved_state ? JSON.parse(saved_state) : default_state;

 $(function() {
   init();

 $('.button').on('click', function() {
    var circle = $(this).attr('data-circle');
    toggleCircle(circle, !state[circle]);
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
 });



function init() {
  for(var key in state) {
     var is_displayed = state[key];
     console.log(});is_displayed);
    toggleCircle(key, is_displayed);
  }
}

function toggleCircle(circle, is_displayed) {
if (is_displayed) {
    $('.'+circle).show()
    state[circle] = true;
} else {
    $('.'+circle).hide()
    state[circle] = false;
}

localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(state));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go here for a straightforward tutorial on cookies:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Add the following functions to your JS (of course modifying them slightly to remove the alert statements, etc.):
setCookie() and getCookie()

Then, on page load you check if the cookie already exists (I'm assuming you name the cookie "toggleStatus") using "getCookie('toggleStatus')".  If they don't exist, create as many of them as you need using:

```
setCookie('toggleStatus','hidden', 30);
setCookie('toggleStatus2','hidden', 30);
```

etc....

If they already do exist, then update the status of the buttons accordingly.

Then on each button click, check the cookies current value, and update them accordingly:

```
if(getCookie('toggleStatus') === 'hidden') {    
    setCookie('toggleStatus', 'show', 30);
} else {
    setCookie('toggleStatus', 'hidden', 30);
}
```

This is an untested answer which may or may not have typos :)